# How to tell if Ng-Repeat has printed x items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I tell if there is 1 item displayed by ng-repeat? Like, `if ng-repeat items === 1: do something.`

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller2">
<form ng-submit="submit()">
   {% csrf_token %}
   Search by name:
   <input ng-model="artistname" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="name in names | filter:artistname | limitTo:10">
       <!-- if number of "name" === 1 I want the form submitted -->
       <td ng-hide="!artistname">
           <a href="" ng-click="submit()">
           {({ name })}
           </a>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This code reads the input from a user to display a list of links that submit the form. What I want is for the form to submit automatically when the initial list of artist names displayed by ng-repeat is down to 1, since there can be only one dataset from the database at that point anyway.

Comment: Essentially, you want to submit the form automatically if there is only one result?  Could you give a little more background on your use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to combine a few answers to get exactly what I was looking for. The `<div>` element below with ng-if and ng-init functions submits the form when there's one name left.

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Search by name:
    <input ng-model="artistname" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

    <div ng-if="(names | filter:artistname).length===1" ng-init="submit()"></div>
</form>

<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="name in names | filter:artistname | limitTo:10">
       <td ng-hide="!artistname">
           <a href="" ng-click="submit()">
           {({ name })}
           </a>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now the form submits automatically when there's one name left in the ng-repeat filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the names array like this:

```
<span ng-if="names.length === 1">Do something</span>
```

Just add ng-if to the same element that has ng-repeat, and then it will be conditional.

Update:

You can listen to the logic in a controller using `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('names', function() {
  if (names.length === 1) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does the "do something" part have to be html? I need ng-if to call the `submit()` function.

Comment: It doesn't. If you need the logic in the angular world, you can watch the `names` attribute for changes and go from there. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this in your form block:

```
<div ng-if="names.length == 1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myform").submit(); 
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer risto provided is along the right lines, just needs to be tweaked to determine if there is only a single value **after** the filter has been applied

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Search by name:
    <input ng-model="artistname" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" 
           ng-disabled="(names | filter:artistname).length === 1" />
 </form>
```

The filtering will change the number of elements displayed, but will **not** change the length of the `names` array.

Comment: That disables my submit button when there is 1 name left. I need it to activate the submit button.

Comment: You can change the logic of the disabled expression to be whatever your business rules dictate. `>= 1` `!== 1` `<= 1`

Comment: I don't need to disable anything though.

Comment: Ok, but regardless, the logic you need to use to determine if there is only one item in the list is: `(names | filter:artistname).length === 1` the key part being the inclusion of the filter in the deterination.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to happen in the controller.

```
if ($scope.names.length === 1) $scope.submit()
```